# power shell script output to txt file

Tags: powershell

This works perfectly on Windows 10 using powershell but fails badly on Win Server 2012 R2.
I have tried many forms using redirect and -outfile but at best end-up with an empty file or broken script.

Can any one help me send the one liner below to a txt file on win server 2012 R2, I'm just not getting it

```
$((Get-WmiObject -Query "select Name, PercentProcessorTime from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor") | foreach-object { write-host "$($_.Name)    :    $($_.PercentProcessorTime)"}) *>&1 > output.txt
```

Comment: As an aside: The CIM cmdlets (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell [Core] (version 6 and above), where all future effort will go, doesn't even _have_ them anymore. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this... note that it is appending to the file, so if you run it twice, you will have two runs' worth of data

```
$((Get-WmiObject -Query "select Name, PercentProcessorTime from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor") | foreach-object { "$($_.Name)    :    $($_.PercentProcessorTime)" >> output.txt})
```

---

---

### EDIT

OP accepted this as the answer, but it's not necessarily the best solution. For a thorough explanation and another solution, I recommend [a different answer submitted for this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62685558/11831920)

Comment: Jonathon: the `>>` is a distraction; just use `>`; the `$(...)` is unnecessary (while it is present in the OP, it's not worth reusing, unless the redundancy is pointed out). Most importantly: it is switching from using `Write-Host` to _implicit_  output of the string to the _success output stream_ that makes your solution work (in PS versions _before_ version 5). Explaining this aspect in your answer is crucial to making it helpful to future readers.

Comment: @mklement0 I tested with the single `>` operator, but it overwrites the file with every iteration of the `Foreach-Object` loop, so the final output only has one line. I tend not to comment on potentially stylistic coding like using `$(...) `

Comment: That's because you put the `>>` _inside_ the `foreach-object` script block - put it _after_ (e.g, `1..10 | ForEach-Object { "[$_]" } > foo.txt`) - that's also much more efficient.

Comment: The use of `$(...)`, generally speaking, is _not_ just a matter of _style_: it can fundamentally alter the behavior of the command (up-front collection _in full, in memory_ vs. memory-throttling _streaming_ behavior).

Comment: Comments on `$(...)` aside: my main point was that the switch from `Write-Host` to implicit output is what needs explaining in your answer for it to be useful.

Comment: @mklement0 All good points. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: @mklement do you have any additional information on use of sub-expressions `$(...)` within expanding strings?  eg mem consequences and/or comparison to other techniques. To keep this clean I can delete this comment after the fact.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Idaho_Huskey I would accept mklement0's answer. It's more explanatory and the code is actually more efficient.

Comment: Jonathon,  while all the answers did work on the win2012 r2 server, from a windows server perspective, the devil is in the details... The file is transferred to a Unix server were a reports is compiled. There were file format issues with all but the append solution (>>). in the other two solutions the data appeared in one long line or each character was on a new line after the transfer regardless of the method of transfer ftp, sftp or using a samba drive map. For that reason I went with the >> approach.

Comment: @Idaho_Huskey: All file operations in Windows PowerShell (and PowerShell [Core] _on Windows_) will result in Windows-style CRLF rather than Unix-style LF-only newlines, irrespective of whether you use `>>` or `>`. The `>`-based solution in my answer neither results in a single long line, nor does it result in each character on its own line - in any PowerShell version since v2. If it does for you, you didn't copy the command correctly.

Comment: @Steven: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54794690/45375

Answer (score 1):

**[`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Host), as the name implies, writes to the *host*, which in a console window is that window's *display* (screen), *bypassing* PowerShell's (success) output stream**, the latter being what the pipeline operator (`|`) and the redirection operator `>` operate on.

**In PowerShell *v5+ only*, `Write-Host` writes to the *information output stream*** (stream number `6` - see the [about_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) help topic; by default, that output still goes to the *host*) and ***can* therefore be redirected** - either via `6>` or via `*>` -  so the catch-all redirection `*>&1`, which redirects *all* streams to the success output stream (`1`), can indeed be used to redirect `Write-Host` to the success output stream, but *not in earlier PowerShell versions* - and **Windows Server 2012 R2 shipped with PowerShell version *4***.

However, in your case **there is no good reason to use `Write-Host` to begin with**: either use [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Output) - the cmdlet whose purpose is to write to the success output stream (`1`) - or, preferably, **use PowerShell's *implicit output* feature**, where any output (return value) not captured in a variable, piped or redirected is *implicitly* written to the success output stream:

```
# Note how the use of "$($_.Name)    :    $($_.PercentProcessorTime)"
# *by itself* implicitly causes it to be *output* (written to the pipeline).
Get-WmiObject -Query "select Name, PercentProcessorTime from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor" |
  Foreach-Object { "$($_.Name)    :    $($_.PercentProcessorTime)" } > output.txt
```

<sup>Note the absence of `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--) in the command, which isn't needed.</sup>

If the specific spacing between the columns isn't important, you can more simply write (since only 2 properties are being select, implicit [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Format-Table) formatting is applied):

```
Get-WmiObject -Query "select Name, PercentProcessorTime from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor" |
  Select-Object Name, PercentProcessorTime > output.txt
```

**Note**: The CIM cmdlets (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, **the WMI cmdlets should be avoided**, not least because PowerShell [Core] (version 6 and above), where all future effort will go, doesn't even *have* them anymore. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).